IF/OR Formula, Compound to Simplified | I want to simplify, narrow down, and have an evolving cell as information is updated on the Excel sheet
I have a cell that I need it to evolve as data is changed, deleted, or added to in the main body of the sheet. (Sheet name "Carton DIM Calculator") I have a very large IF/OR formula that will soon, I suspect, reach a character max point. So before it does that I want to fix it but I'm not sure on where to begin. Also to add to the reasoning I need it fixed is every time I must change information on the sheet I have to go in and change the formula manually. It is time consuming and it's now becoming more and more of a hassle to update. It originally was just a few If/Or's, but our shipping cases have grown from about 10 box sizes to 58 box sizes.
The point of the formula is to return a specified box size based on the dimensions user inputs. Yes, we have a system that does this when a customer places an order and it works 99% flawless on that side. But this side is for setting up new inventory as it comes in the warehouse or when we need to ship something outside of the customer ordering side.
I'm not sure if what I'm currently asking is even achievable or if I will have to manually update this as information changes.
Below is the formula I currently have:
Formula is in Cell F2
Information being called for the formula is between B4 - G4 down to B61 - G61
=IF(OR(B2=0,C2=0,D2=0,B2="",C2="",D2=""),"Pending",
 IF(AND((G2<=G4)*(B2<=B4-0.25)*(C2<=C4-0.25)*(D2<=D4)),"#ENV",
 IF(AND((G2<=G5)*(B2<=B5-0.25)*(C2<=C5-0.25)*(D2<=D5)),"#99",
 IF(AND((G2<=G6)*(B2<=B6-0.25)*(C2<=C6-0.25)*(D2<=D6)),"ENV5",
 IF(AND((G2<=G7)*(B2<=B7-0.25)*(C2<=C7-0.25)*(D2<=D7)),"ENV2",
 IF(AND((G2<=G8)*(B2<=B8-0.25)*(C2<=C8-0.25)*(D2<=D8)),"ENV3",
 IF(AND((G2<=G9)*(B2<=B9-0.25)*(C2<=C9-0.25)*(D2<=D9)),"ENV4",
 IF(AND((G2<=G10)*(B2<=B10-0.25)*(C2<=C10-0.25)*(D2<=D10)),"#30",
 IF(AND((G2<=G11)*(B2<=B11-0.25)*(C2<=C11-0.25)*(D2<=D11)),"#04",
 IF(AND((G2<=G12)*(B2<=B12-0.25)*(C2<=C12-0.25)*(D2<=D12)),"#02",
 IF(AND((G2<=G13)*(B2<=B13-0.25)*(C2<=C13-0.25)*(D2<=D13)),"#49",
 IF(AND((G2<=G14)*(B2<=B14-0.25)*(C2<=C14-0.25)*(D2<=D14)),"#46",
 IF(AND((G2<=G15)*(B2<=B15-0.25)*(C2<=C15-0.25)*(D2<=D15)),"#10_1",
 IF(AND((G2<=G16)*(B2<=B16-0.25)*(C2<=C16-0.25)*(D2<=D16)),"#09",
 IF(AND((G2<=G17)*(B2<=B17-0.25)*(C2<=C17-0.25)*(D2<=D17)),"#10",
 IF(AND((G2<=G18)*(B2<=B18-0.25)*(C2<=C18-0.25)*(D2<=D18)),"#43",
 IF(AND((G2<=G19)*(B2<=B19-0.25)*(C2<=C19-0.25)*(D2<=D19)),"#06",
 IF(AND((G2<=G20)*(B2<=B20-0.25)*(C2<=C20-0.25)*(D2<=D20)),"#45",
 IF(AND((G2<=G21)*(B2<=B21-0.25)*(C2<=C21-0.25)*(D2<=D21)),"#03_1",
 IF(AND((G2<=G22)*(B2<=B22-0.25)*(C3<=C22-0.25)*(D2<=D22)),"#13_1",
 IF(AND((G2<=G23)*(B2<=B23-0.25)*(C2<=C23-0.25)*(D2<=D23)),"#03",
 IF(AND((G2<=G24)*(B2<=B24-0.25)*(C2<=C24-0.25)*(D2<=D24)),"#48",
 IF(AND((G2<=G25)*(B2<=B25-0.25)*(C2<=C25-0.25)*(D2<=D25)),"#42",
 IF(AND((G2<=G26)*(B2<=B26-0.25)*(C3<=C26-0.25)*(D2<=D26)),"#13",
 IF(AND((G2<=G27)*(B2<=B27-0.25)*(C2<=C27-0.25)*(D2<=D27)),"#05",
 IF(AND((G2<=G28)*(B2<=B28-0.25)*(C2<=C28-0.25)*(D2<=D28)),"#08",
 IF(AND((G2<=G29)*(B2<=B29-0.25)*(C2<=C29-0.25)*(D2<=D29)),"#07_1",
 IF(AND((G2<=G30)*(B2<=B30-0.25)*(C2<=C30-0.25)*(D2<=D30)),"#41",
 IF(AND((G2<=G31)*(B2<=B31-0.25)*(C2<=C31-0.25)*(D2<=D31)),"#33_1",
 IF(AND((G2<=G32)*(B2<=B32-0.25)*(C2<=C32-0.25)*(D2<=D32)),"#22",
 IF(AND((G2<=G33)*(B2<=B33-0.25)*(C2<=C33-0.25)*(D2<=D33)),"#26_1",
 IF(AND((G2<=G34)*(B2<=B34-0.25)*(C2<=C34-0.25)*(D2<=D34)),"#32_1",
 IF(AND((G2<=G35)*(B2<=B35-0.25)*(C2<=C35-0.25)*(D2<=D35)),"#25_1",
 IF(AND((G2<=G36)*(B2<=B36-0.25)*(C2<=C36-0.25)*(D2<=D36)),"#14_2",
 IF(AND((G2<=G37)*(B2<=B37-0.25)*(C2<=C37-0.25)*(D2<=D37)),"#07",
 IF(AND((G2<=G38)*(B2<=B38-0.25)*(C2<=C38-0.25)*(D2<=D38)),"#24_1",
 IF(AND((G2<=G39)*(B2<=B39-0.25)*(C2<=C39-0.25)*(D2<=D39)),"#32",
 IF(AND((G2<=G40)*(B2<=B40-0.25)*(C2<=C40-0.25)*(D2<=D40)),"#33",
 IF(AND((G2<=G41)*(B2<=B41-0.25)*(C2<=C41-0.25)*(D2<=D41)),"#21_1",
 IF(AND((G2<=G42)*(B2<=B42-0.25)*(C2<=C42-0.25)*(D2<=D42)),"#31",
 IF(AND((G2<=G43)*(B2<=B43-0.25)*(C2<=C43-0.25)*(D2<=D43)),"#20_1",
 IF(AND((G2<=G44)*(B2<=B44-0.25)*(C2<=C44-0.25)*(D2<=D44)),"#26",
 IF(AND((G2<=G45)*(B2<=B45-0.25)*(C2<=C45-0.25)*(D2<=D45)),"#24",
 IF(AND((G2<=G46)*(B2<=B46-0.25)*(C2<=C46-0.25)*(D2<=D46)),"#25",
 IF(AND((G2<=G47)*(B2<=B47-0.25)*(C2<=C47-0.25)*(D2<=D47)),"#21",
 IF(AND((G2<=G48)*(B2<=B48-0.25)*(C2<=C48-0.25)*(D2<=D48)),"#23_2",
 IF(AND((G2<=G49)*(B2<=B49-0.25)*(C2<=C49-0.25)*(D2<=D49)),"#14_1",
 IF(AND((G2<=G50)*(B2<=B50-0.25)*(C2<=C50-0.25)*(D2<=D50)),"#20",
 IF(AND((G2<=G51)*(B2<=B51-0.25)*(C2<=C51-0.25)*(D2<=D51)),"#15_1",
 IF(AND((G2<=G52)*(B2<=B52-0.25)*(C2<=C52-0.25)*(D2<=D52)),"#23_1",
 IF(AND((G2<=G53)*(B2<=B53-0.25)*(C2<=C53-0.25)*(D2<=D53)),"#14",
 IF(AND((G2<=G54)*(B2<=B54-0.25)*(C2<=C54-0.25)*(D2<=D54)),"#23",
 IF(AND((G2<=G55)*(B2<=B55-0.25)*(C2<=C55-0.25)*(D2<=D55)),"#15",
 IF(AND((G2<=G56)*(B2<=B56-0.25)*(C2<=C56-0.25)*(D2<=D56)),"#51X_2",
 IF(AND((G2<=G57)*(B2<=B57-0.25)*(C2<=C57-0.25)*(D2<=D57)),"#51X_1",
 IF(AND((G2<=G58)*(B2<=B58-0.25)*(C2<=C58-0.25)*(D2<=D58)),"#51X","OS3"
))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

Images to help:

B2-E2 are 'user' input, F2 is above formula, G2 has a working formula as does H2



These are usually hidden from user and these cells are locked to keep anyone from accidentally changing the values
glimpse of the cells and what they look like


Thank you.
I just keep editing the current formula but it is becoming more and more cumbersome to keep up and change. Simply seeking help on how I can fix this and have no idea where to begin.

Sorry, but you don't expect us to understand the formula, don't you? Please describe your requirement in words. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Had to reformat your formula for readability - Excel wasn't accepting it as the forum mark-down language was removing the *.  By the looks of it you should be able to do some kind of lookup on that second table to return the Container Type values.  Hard to tell what's what as the column/row numbers aren't shown in the second image.

@Ike Requirements are very simple: the box should fit the freight by dimensions and the volume.

No need to plague OP with unnecessary questions.

I guess the volume check is extra, but other parameters like max weight can be important. OP can add related checks later.

@DarrenBartrup-Cook Thank you for making this more readable. I have to do this a lot myself and then correct formula/code to get it to work correctly. I know this is not best practice but I suffer with dyslexia and it helps to see numbers/letters.

Glad it helped.  Remember to tick one of the answers.... if the answer worked for you.  It helps to notify the question has been answered and gives some kudos to whoever answered it.

Lookup with Multiple Criteria in an Excel Table

You could put the data in an Excel (structured) table.
Whether you have MS365 or not, you could use the following formula.

=IF(COUNTBLANK(B2:D2)>0,"Pending",
    IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[Container Type],MATCH(1,(G2<=Table1[Volume])
        *(B2<=(Table1[Full Length]-0.25))*(C2<=(Table1[Full Width]-0.25))
        *(D2<=(Table1[Full Height])),0)),"OS3"))



Surely this is the only sane way to do it?

It's the only solution! But as I wrote above, G2<=Table1[Volume] is extra. Box's volume will be greater than freight's volume if each box dimension is greater than the related freight dimension. The main condition is what Volume should be ordered ascending.

@Christian You can simply add new rows below the table. Don't miss to sort the table by Volume.

It never crossed my mind to turn this into a table... *slap forehead! Yes, this does greatly simplify the issue of needing to add new data. I make tables all of the time for use in other aspects, I don't know why it didn't occur to me to do such a thing here. Thank you!

Try filtering your data down to the row that's needed and then taking just the first row of whatever's returned.
=IF(SUM($B$2:$D$2,$G$2)=0,"Pending",IFERROR(TAKE(FILTER($F$4:$F$61,($G$2<=$G$4:$G$61)*($B$2<=$B$4:$B$61-0.25)*($C$2<=$C$4:$C$61-0.25)*($D$2<=$D$4:$D$61)),1),"OS3"))  

Edit:  Adding IFERROR to return OS3.


Lists all accepted sizes.
This is the formula in K4
=LET(res,TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,BYROW(B4:G12,LAMBDA(a,IF((XLOOKUP($B$2,CHOOSECOLS(a,1),TRUE,FALSE,1))* (XLOOKUP($C$2,CHOOSECOLS(a,2),TRUE,FALSE,1))*(XLOOKUP($D$2,CHOOSECOLS(a,3),TRUE,FALSE,1))* (XLOOKUP($G$2,CHOOSECOLS(a,6),TRUE,FALSE,1)),CHOOSECOLS(a,5),"")))), IF(LEN(res)=0,"PENDING",res))


VBasic2008's would be my first choice, but here's another with XLOOKUP,

assuming table is sorted by volume
adjust F4:F100 to match the table

=LET(d, LAMBDA(c, INDEX(B4:INDEX(F:F, XMATCH(, F4:F100)), , c)),
    largest, "OS3",
    vol, B2 * C2 * D2,
    vol_full, d(1) * d(2) * d(3), type, d(5),
    match_dim, (vol <= vol_full) *
        (B2 <= d(1) - 0.25) * (C2 <= d(2) - 0.25) * (D2 <= d(3)),
    IF(vol, XLOOKUP(1, match_dim, type, largest), "Pending"))


